# Reading from a Text File in PHP

Tags: php

I am using this code to try and read the values in a text file.

```
$mapFile = fopen('config/map.txt', 'r') or die ("Can't open config file");
while ($line = fread($mapfile,filesize('config/map.txt')))
{
    echo $line;
}
```

Instead I keep getting this error.

```
Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. How can I read the text in the file properly?

Comment: Your variable is `$mapFile`, and you're trying to fread `$mapfile`. Variables names are case sensitive. Also, consider `file_get_contents()` instead.

Comment: @jbafford `file_get_contents()` isn't really suitable for large files as it loads all the file in memory. Reading a file line by line is far better in any case in my honest opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP variables are case sensitive. `$mapFile !== $mapfile`.

```
$mapFile = fopen('config/map.txt', 'r'); // don't need `or die()`
while ($line = fread($mapFile, filesize('config/map.txt')))
{
    echo $line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is `$mapFile`, and you're trying to fread `$mapfile`. Variables names in PHP are case sensitive. Also, consider [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) instead, which will open the file, get its entire contents, and close the file, in one function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to read full file

```
$file=file('config/map.txt');
foreach($file as $line)
{
echo $line;
}
```

Or simply

```
echo file_get_contents('config/map.txt');
```